# Embed svg in PDF using pdfsharp

Tags: asp.net-mvc, svg, pdfsharp, migradoc

Any body I want to export chart data made with d3.js in to PDF file using PDFSharp and Migradoc. I am not able to find any example. So can anybody give some example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `PDFSharp` and the external program `Inkscape`. First, I did a function to use the command line of Inkscape (remember to install the program before trying!) to create a pdf from svg like so:

```
public void ConvertSvgToPdfWithInkscape(string tempSvgFilePath, string pdfFilePath)
{
    // Path to the Inkscape executable
    string inkscapePath = "C:/Program Files/Inkscape/bin/inkscape.exe"; // Replace with the actual path

    // Construct the command for converting SVG to PDF
    string command = $"\"{inkscapePath}\" \"{tempSvgFilePath}\" --export-filename=\"{pdfFilePath}\"";

    // Create a process to execute the Inkscape command
    using (Process process = new Process())
    {
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        };

        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();

        // Execute the Inkscape command
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine(command);
        process.StandardInput.Flush();
        process.StandardInput.Close();

        // Wait for the process to finish
        process.WaitForExit();

        // Check if there were any errors
        string errorOutput = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorOutput))
        {
            throw new Exception($"Inkscape Error: {errorOutput}");
        }
    }
            
}
```

And then I add a page to a document with the svgs using PDFSharp's `AddPage`  method:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using PdfSharp.Pdf;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;

Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);

var document = new PdfDocument();

string tempPDF = "temp.pdf";

var svg = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.svg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

ConvertSvgToPdfWithInkscape(svg, tempPDF);    

PdfDocument inputDocument = PdfReader.Open(tempPDF, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);

document.AddPage(inputDocument.Pages[0]);

// Do whatever you need to the page of the document

File.Delete(tempPDF);

string fileName = path + "/output.pdf";

// Save
document.Save(fileName);
```

If you don't need to do anything to the page of the document and it's a pdf with a single page, you can omit the PDFSharp part and just use Inkscape function.

Check my recent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76841766/attempt-to-embed-svg-into-pdf-programmatically-in-c-sharp-open-source-solution) if you need to add more pages using the same method, however I am looking for a more convenient way if possible!