# Attempt to Embed SVG into PDF programmatically in C# [Open Source solution]

Tags: c#, pdf, svg, itext7, pdfsharp

I've been trying to create pdf pages from generated SVG via C# programmatically for quite a while now. I want to share my workaround to do so, since most of the offering solutions are not free...

SVG stands for Scalable Vector Graphics. SVG images are defined in a vector graphics format and stored in XML text files. SVG images can thus be scaled in size without loss of quality, and SVG files can be searched, indexed, scripted, and compressed. This behaviour allows to zoom in and never lose quality, which in a pdf (specially when you want to use plots and charts) would be such an improvement against png or jpeg.

Most of the PDFs generators need to render the image, so they lose the scalability property that we are interested in, however, there are some tools that seem to create this pdf from svg and here I will show you how we could create a longer document.

## Test 1: PDFSharp + Inkscape

For the first successful attempt I used `PDFSharp` and the external program `Inkscape`. Let me omit the SVG generation, for the sake of simplicity and let's assume that we have two SVG images inside the folder where we are working on. First, I did a function to use the command line of Inkscape (remember to install the program before trying!) to create a pdf from svg like so:

```
public void ConvertSvgToPdfWithInkscape(string tempSvgFilePath, string pdfFilePath)
{
    // Path to the Inkscape executable
    string inkscapePath = "C:/Program Files/Inkscape/bin/inkscape.exe"; // Replace with the actual path

    // Construct the command for converting SVG to PDF
    string command = $"\"{inkscapePath}\" \"{tempSvgFilePath}\" --export-filename=\"{pdfFilePath}\"";

    // Create a process to execute the Inkscape command
    using (Process process = new Process())
    {
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        };

        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();

        // Execute the Inkscape command
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine(command);
        process.StandardInput.Flush();
        process.StandardInput.Close();

        // Wait for the process to finish
        process.WaitForExit();

        // Check if there were any errors
        string errorOutput = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorOutput))
        {
            throw new Exception($"Inkscape Error: {errorOutput}");
        }
    }
            
}
```

And then, in a loop, I start adding pages to a document with the svgs using PDFSharp's `AddPage`  method:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using PdfSharp.Pdf;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;

Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);

var document = new PdfDocument();

string tempPDF = "temp.pdf";

var list = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.svg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

for (int ev = 0; ev < list.Length; ev++)
{
                
    ConvertSvgToPdfWithInkscape(list[ev], tempPDF);    

    PdfDocument inputDocument = PdfReader.Open(tempPDF, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);

    document.AddPage(inputDocument.Pages[0]);

}
File.Delete(tempPDF);

string fileName = path + "/output.pdf";

// Save and start View
document.Save(fileName);
```

I don't like this solution because we use an external program and it's not C# native but it does the job!

## Test 2: PDFSharp + iText7

My second attempt was using `iText7`, I found out that I needed to install `itext7.bouncy-castle-fips-adapter` and `itext7.font-asian` in order to work (no clue why!). I kept using `PDFSharp` for merging the pdfs but I know that could be done with iText. This was the trial:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;
using iText.Svg.Converter;
using iText.Layout.Font;
using iText.Svg.Processors.Impl;

Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);

var document = new PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument();

string tempPDF = "temp.pdf";

var list = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.svg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

for (int ev = 0; ev < list.Length; ev++)
{
    FontProvider provider = new FontProvider();

    SvgConverterProperties props = new SvgConverterProperties();
    props.SetCharset("Windows-1252");
    props.SetFontProvider(provider);

    FileStream svgPath = File.Open(list[ev], FileMode.Open);
    FileStream pdfPath = File.Create(tempPDF);
    SvgConverter.CreatePdf(svgPath, pdfPath, props);

    PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument inputDocument = PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfReader.Open(tempPDF, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);

    document.AddPage(inputDocument.Pages[0]);

}
File.Delete(tempPDF);

string fileName = path + "/output.pdf";

// Save and start View
document.Save(fileName);
```

This procedure was the best in terms of speed and being C# native, however the results were not the perfect ones, so I hope that here we can discuss what's going on and hopefully find out a final solution to accomplish this, because SVG and pdfs look amazing together! :)

As this post is huge (atleast for me), I will be editing the errors that I might have done, like typos or wrong Copy-Paste of my code (I tried to omit the non-essential part). Be patient please!

So the question is: has someone been able to do it programatically like my test 2 but with an accurate result? Or do you have a guess what is going on that is not converting correctly the svg to pdf in the second case?

**SVG test samples**
Trying to attach...
[svg1](https://svgshare.com/i/w7U.svg)
[svg2](https://svgshare.com/i/wBC.svg)

**Result test 1 snapshot**
[exact result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQ49n.png)

**Result test 2 snapshot**
[close result but not perfect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUAAE.png)

Comment: So, what is the ❓

Comment: sorry I got that deep that I forgot my question hahaha try to get working test 2 as perfect as test 1. If you see the svgs in the pdf of the second test, they are not the same...

Comment: SVG is XML format.  So I would extract the Xml Elements using An XML net library.  SVG can contain many layers so you may need more than one layer.  There are XML Viewers that you can find on the Net the may do some of the functions you need.

Comment: @jdweng thanks for your comment, I am not an expert in XML so I don't really know how to proceed from getting the XML elements to convert them into PDF. Are you suggesting using an online conversor? If it's so, it's not what I wanted, since I want to do programatically.  If you are offering a coding solution to do it and you have time, please provide me a simple sample so I can try to develop that idea! :D

Comment: XML is text so start by opening the XML in a text editor.  See if figure is multiple layers to see what the root cause of issue.  This looks like a layer issue. The library you are using is using one color so when you display two layers it is simply overlaying the two layers.  A good SVG viewer will allow you to view with lots of options.

Comment: Try : https://github.com/typst/svg2pdf

Answer (score 0):

Since you are depending on defaulting to Windows Licensed Fonts the application needs to run in MS Windows thus by far the simplest is use the native system to "Generate" the PDF with imbedded SegoeUI fonts and that is a simple headless command on any Current Windows.

Wrap.cmd

```
echo ^<html^>^<head^>^<style^>@media print { @page { size: 1200px 920px; }}^</style^>^<body style="margin-top: -10px;width: 1200px;"^>^<div style="height: 900px;">^>>wrap.html
copy wrap.html+w7u.svg wrap1.html && copy wrap1.html+wbc.svg wrap2.html && echo ^</div^>^</body^>^</html^>>>wrap2.html
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --headless --print-to-pdf="%cd%\fred1.pdf" --no-pdf-header-footer "%cd%\wrap2.html"
```

[image]

You may wonder why I had to "fiddle" page size up by 20pts and that is just the way HTML behaves with the 16bit BOMs, hence I always find it's a different value for each mix of files!.